# Почему значение в $_SESSION на шаг впереди, чем $_POST

Tags: php, post, input, сессия, переменные

**Почему при нажатии на кнопку, значения в переменных $_SESSION['TOKEN'] и $_POST['tok'] не равны??????????**
**var_dump выводит FALSE**
Помогите люди добрые!

```
$_SESSION['TOKEN'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));


<form>
    <input name="tok" value="<?=$_SESSION['TOKEN']?>">
    <button type="submit" name="save">Сохранить</button>
</form>


if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    var_dump(hash_equals($_SESSION['TOKEN'], $_POST['tok']));
}
```

**При нажатии на кнопку, в $_POST['tok'] находится предыдущее значение $_SESSION['TOKEN'] и поэтому при сравнении они не равны. Как такое происходит???**

Comment: потому что пост-значение существует только когда ты отправил форму, а значение сессии записалось давным-давно, ты же страницу явно не 1 раз загружал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сталкивался с такой проблемой давно при получении кода капчи.
Код записывался в сессию и при нажатии на кнопку отправки формы введённый код с картинки выдавал ошибку, мол капча не верна. И как оказалось значение капчи в переменной сессии было на шаг в переди вводимого кода в инпут, а картика выдавала именно предыдущий код.
Банальщина, но уверен большинство новичков столкнуться с этой темой.

Answer (score 1):

Немного переписал код, но вопрос всё равно актуален: Почему переменная $_SESSION на шаг впереди $_POST.
А сделал я код такой, может кому поможет и токен так же обновляется:

```
if (!$_SESSION['TOKEN']) $_SESSION['TOKEN'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));


<form>
    <input name="tok" value="<?=$_SESSION['TOKEN']?>">
    <button type="submit" name="save">Сохранить</button>
</form>


if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    var_dump(hash_equals($_SESSION['TOKEN'], $_POST['tok']));
    $_SESSION['TOKEN'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
}
```

Вот такой банальный камень под водой от джуна)